# Adding editable columns to GUI table in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, uitableview, user-interface

My problem is that I need to add new columns to existing table made in GUI Matlab. I am doing it with the code quoted below but there is one problem - new columns are not editable. Anyone know how to force it to them?

```
database = get(handles.table,'Data');

[height,width] = size(database);

database(1:height,width+1) = cellstr(get(handles.edit13,'String'));
database(1:height,width+2) = {str2num(get(handles.edit12,'String'))};
database(1,width+3) = cellstr(' ');

set(handles.table,'Data', database);
```

Comment: uiTables have a `ColumnEditable` property. Try running `get(handles.table,'ColumnEditable')` and see what's returned.

Comment: @jerad: Strange, it onli shows two 1 (my table has only two columns at start) even though I have added few more using this code above...

Comment: Acctualy you have helped me! Added this:
'wektortrue=true(1,width)
set(handles.table,'ColumnEditable',wektortrue);'
Thanks @jerad!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. it solves my problem:

```
wektortrue=true(1,width)
set(handles.table,'ColumnEditable',wektortrue);
```